# How to get a Line string in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using the code to get line string feature.when ever i am using coord2 array i am getting correct line string but whenever i am using points array i am not getting correct line string .I have observed that coordinate values in points array are stored in same format as in coord2 array.

This is my code:

```
   for(i=0;i<pathArr.length;i++)
      {
        var temp=(pathArr[i]+"").split(",");
      //console.log("lat lon "+temp[1]+"   " +temp[0]);
          points[i]= [temp[1],temp[0]];
     }
      //window.alert(points);

   var coord2=[[76,22],[77,24],[78,25],[66,12],[65,15],[76,22],[77,24],[78,25],[66,12],[65,15] ,[76,22],[77,24],[78,25],[66,12],[65,15],[78,25], [66,12],[65,15],[76,22]];
 window.alert(coord2);
  feature = new ol.Feature({
 geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(points)
     });
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Does something not work as expected or is there an error? It isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

See [API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragZoom.html#setActive):

```
dragZoom.setActive(false);
```

Comment: @vani if the answer is what you're looking for, mark it as correct.